# Removing dotted borders on click

Tags: html, css

I am using this CSS to remove dotted borders which appear when hyperlinks are clicked

```
a:active, a:focus, input {
    outline: 0;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:0;
}
```

This is working fine, but doesn't work on input buttons which have background images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not my place to question your design decisions, so here you go.

Just add this to any link's you want to remove the dotted line

```
onfocus="if(this.blur)this.blur()"
```

Answer (score 6):

It isn't working fine. It is rendering it impossible to navigate the design without a mouse.

See http://24ways.org/2009/dont-lose-your-focus for a reasonable compromise.

Comment: The solution in this article is same what I am using but my problem is it doesn't works on input buttons with background images.

Answer (score 4):

You could add an `onclick: blur();` so it keeps it tab-happy and doesn't ruin the design when clicked.

But for the record, this seems to work cross browser. The first part for IE, the second for FF:

```
input, input:active, input:focus{
    outline: 0;
    outline-style:none;
    outline-width:0;
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need classes to differentiate which links have dotted borders and which do not. Using the img selector won't be enough.

Style your input tags to not have dotted borders; you could even use a class for your input buttons if you have more than one style (Clear, Submit, Cancel, etc.)