# CSS submit input black border

Tags: css, input, submit, border

every time I click submit button there's a black 1px border around it.

How to get rid of it?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SEFp4/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing dotted borders on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1874815/removing-dotted-borders-on-click)

Comment: @anonymous - I ain't seeing a black border

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there'sa black border is as this component get the focus.

setting the attributes of element's focus like this:input:focus{ outline:none }

Answer (score 1):

add this directly before the offending button or at the start of your form

```
    <input type="submit" value="" style="height:0;overflow:auto;position:absolute;left:-9999px;" />
```

or add in

```
    .button{
    filter:chroma[color=#000000]
    }
```

which looks for all the black in the class and makes it transparent, imo this isn't very good as it makes your buttons look rubbish if you have applied styles=

Answer (score 1):

I blogged about this issue here: http://markmintoff.com/2012/01/remove-internet-explorer-black-border-around-button/

Essentially you can use the follow style to remove the offending border simply and effectively.

```
    input[type=submit],
    input[type=reset],
    input[type=button]
    {
        filter:chroma(color=#000000);
        color:#010101;
    }
```